# How to get specific commit from GitLab project

Tags: c#, .net, gitlab, commit, windows-forms-designer

I am developing (so new at it) an application with Windows Forms C# in Visual Studio and I need to get a specific commit from a GitLab project.

I have seen many examples about for GitHub. I have tried this way (do not know if is the correct one):

Download repository at a particular commit using the 7-digit SHA1:

```
 var Token = "xxxx";              
 var url = "http://{my_domain}/{user}/{project_name}/repository/archive/{shor_id}.zip";
 var path = @"C:\GitLab\My_Projects";

      try 
      {
         using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
         {
            var credentials = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}:", Token);
            credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials);
            var contents = client.GetByteArrayAsync(url).Result;
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, contents);
         }
      }
      catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
      {
            backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Problem downloading");
      }
```

But I get this error:

```
'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll. Access denied to 'C:\GitLab\My_Projects'.
```

As I said before, I am new at it and probably may have said something stupid, sorry in advance.
If someone knows about the subject, I would love to explain or help me with this concept.

Comment: *`Access denied to 'C:\GitLab\My_Projects'`* is clearly a *local* permissions issue and has nothing to do with GitHub or GitLab.

Comment: Pedantic: you're not downloading *a commit*; you're downloading an archive of the repository *at* a particular commit. Also, it doesn't make any sense to try and "clone" a commit. You clone a project which contains numerous commits.

Comment: Yes, I know that I am getting the repository of a certain commit and if I clone, I get all the projects with all the commits.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think you do understand, because this URL you made up is not valid, and even the concept is illogical: `$"http://{my_domain}/{user}/{project_name}/{short_id_commit}.git`

Comment: Do you know how I can resolve the permission issue? I am using a Token and I do not understand why I have access problems.

Comment: It has nothing to do with your token, it means your Windows user can't write to that directory.

Comment: But I am able to clone a whole project to that directory, is not that weird?

Comment: Try writing some basic code that just creates a simple text file, and reduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I achived the solution. I took another direction using GitLab API.
If someone would like to look at the result I arrived, here you have the code:

```
var url_sha = $"http://{my_gitlab_domain}/api/v4/projects/{id_project}/repository/archive.zip? 
private_token={my_token}&sha={short_id_commit}";
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync(url_sha);
var local_path = @"C:\GitLab\My_Projects";

using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
{
     var fileInfo = new FileInfo(local_path + ".zip");
     using (var fileStream = fileInfo.OpenWrite())
     {
           await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
     }
}
```